# Is it possible to search an entire JSON object regardless of how deep it is for a specific keyword with JQ?

Tags: json, jq

For any JSON object, for example,

```
{
  "Book1": {
    "Genres": [
      "horror",
      "thriller",
      "drama"
    ],
    "Description": "Extremely scary book.",
    "Author": "Jane Doe"
  },
  "Book2": {
    "Genres": [
      "Romance",
      "drama"
    ],
    "Description": "Very romantic book.",
    "Author": "John Doe"
  }
}
```

Is it possible to do a general search over every single key? For example, if you search for "horror" it would return

```
{
      "Book1": {
        "Genres": [
          "horror",
          "thriller",
          "drama"
        ],
        "Description": "Extremely scary book.",
        "Author": "Jane Doe"
      }
}
```

as the word is found in the "Genres" or if you search for "romantic" it would return Book2 as the word is contained in the description. I want to avoid having to specify the key in which the value is found in but rather have a general search over the entire object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `..` to traverse the tree, `strings` to compare only strings, `any` to return true on first match, and `map_values` to retain the original tree structure.

```bash
jq 'map_values(select(any(..; strings == "horror")))'
```

```json
{
  "Book1": {
    "Genres": [
      "horror",
      "thriller",
      "drama"
    ],
    "Description": "Extremely scary book.",
    "Author": "Jane Doe"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HMrfCgREMf5)

To include substrings in the search, use `contains` instead:

```bash
jq 'map_values(select(any(.. | strings; contains("romantic"))))'
```

```json
{
  "Book2": {
    "Genres": [
      "Romance",
      "drama"
    ],
    "Description": "Very romantic book.",
    "Author": "John Doe"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/eT072VePoOR)

You may also want to convert to upper or lower case using `ascii_upcase` or `ascii_downcase` to have a case-insensitive search, or use `test` for a regex search.